# Handle push notifications for Multiple Device/Multiple User Login in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, notifications, push-notification

I integrated push notification in my app. User will able to login/registration in the app.

User can able to login in multiple device simultaneously.

So, how can I manage the push notification in multiple device?

**How facebook/popular app handle this?**

**Give me some guidance**

**Thank you**

Answer (score 0):

Push Notification works on Device tokens, doesn't matter, how many devices are registered per user. You just need to manage number of device per user. You can also maintain session to track if user is logged in into app or not. Your server will send notification to user on multiple devices. Your app should send device tokens to server on which user logged in or register.